# Sin validación de xml por un complemento

Tags: xml, archivo, validación, xsd, validate

Obtengo el siguiente error de un validador de xml.
/ns:ControlesVolumetricos/ns:PRODUCTO/ns:REPORTEDEVOLUMENMENSUAL/ns:RECEPCIONES/ns:Complemento/
ns:Complemento_Comercializacion: Hijo inesperado con la etiqueta 'Covol:NACIONAL' en la posición 1.

Y el xml tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
<Covol:Complemento>
<Covol:Complemento_Comercializacion>
<ns:NACIONAL>
<ns:RfcClienteOProveedor>xxx</ns:RfcClienteOProveedor>
<ns:NombreClienteOProveedor>xxx</ns:NombreClienteOProveedor>
<ns:CFDIs>
<ns:CFDI>xxx</ns:CFDI>
<ns:TipoCFDI>Ingreso</ns:TipoCFDI>
<ns:PrecioVentaOCompraOContrap>0</ns:PrecioVentaOCompraOContrap>
<ns:FechaYHoraTransaccion>xxx</ns:FechaYHoraTransaccion>
<ns:VolumenDocumentado>
<ns:ValorNumerico>0</ns:ValorNumerico>
<ns:UM>UM03</ns:UM>
</ns:VolumenDocumentado>
</ns:CFDIs>
</ns:NACIONAL>
```

Porque me relaciona el Covol:Nacional si me encuentro dentro del complemento ns?

Comment: Deberías haber mostrado el esquema XSD también. ¿O cómo esperas que alguien pueda explicar el mensaje sin conocer el esquema?